# simple string list in c is leaking memory(malloc and realloc)

Tags: c, xcode, malloc

the problem is I can't free it,the console output pointer are the same inside free function, the xcode detected  at the line from function StringList_add when realloc called.

```
typedef struct stringlist_s {
        int max_str;
        char **str;
}stringlist_t;

//functions
stringlist_t *StringList_new()
{
    stringlist_t *lst = (stringlist_t *)malloc(sizeof(stringlist_t));

    return lst;
}

void StringList_add(stringlist_t *str_list,char *str)
{
    if(!str)
        return;
    if(!str_list)
        return;

    str_list->str = (char **)realloc(str_list->str, sizeof(char *)  * (str_list->max_str+1));

    str_list->str[str_list->max_str] = (char *)malloc(strlen(str) + 1);

    memcpy(str_list->str[str_list->max_str], str, strlen(str) + 1);

    str_list->max_str++;
}

void StringList_release(stringlist_t *strList)
{
    if(!strList) {
        printf("Releasing empty pointer\n");
         return;
    }

    for(int i = 0 ; i < strList->max_str; ++i )
    {
        free(strList->str[i]);
        printf("pointer inside is %p\n",strList->str[i]);
    }

    printf("list before is  %p\n",strList);
    free(strList);
    printf("list  now is %p\n",strList);  //value is the same as previous printf

}
```

I just use this to test the code above:

```
stringList_t *a = StringList_new();
StringList_add(a,"abc");
StringList_add(a,"edf");
StringList_release(a);
```

Comment: Use `valgrind` and `gdb` to debug your memory leak, or else use Boehm's conservative garbage collector (i.e. replace `malloc` by `GC_malloc` etc.)

Comment: `printf("list  now is %p\n",strList);  //value is the same as previous printf`, that's normal, `free`ing a pointer doesn't usually change the address the pointer points to, you just mustn't dereference it between the `free` and pointing it to some valid memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A problem is that `StringList_new()` allocates a new `stringList_t` but never initialises it members. At the call to `realloc()`:

```
str_list->str = (char **)realloc(str_list->str, sizeof(char *)  * 
    (str_list->max_str+1));
```

neither `str_list->str` or `str_list->max_str` have been initialised. From the reference page for [`realloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc):

> It must be previously allocated by malloc(), calloc() or realloc() and not yet freed with free(), otherwise, the results are undefined.

which will be the case when used with an unitialised pointer.

Change to:

```
stringlist_t *StringList_new()
{
    stringlist_t *lst = malloc(sizeof(*lst));
    lst->max_str = 0;
    lst->str     = NULL;

    return lst;
}
```

Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` or `realloc()`. Passing a `NULL` pointer to `realloc()` is fine, it behaves like `malloc()` in that case. When using `realloc()` store the return value in a temporary pointer variable to avoid a memory leak in the event that `realloc()` fails:

```
char** tmp = realloc(str_list->str, sizeof(*tmp)  * (str_list->max_str+1));
if (tmp)
{
    str_list->str = tmp;
}
```

Note I did not use `calloc()` in `StringList_new()` as according the C standard all bits zero need not represent a null pointer.

Comment: sorry max_str is just a typo,it should be int not int *, about str I did realloc it later,